# invalid read of size 1 when initializing c++ string from char* in two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, initialization

the title pretty much describes the problem. the valgrind output, is for example:

```
==18866== Invalid read of size 1
==18866==    at 0x4A07F64: strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:403)
==18866==    by 0x3AD509CF1F: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==18866==    by 0x401809: Employee::Employee(char const*, int, char**) (Employee.C:24)
==18866==    by 0x405F59: main (main.C:321)
==18866==  Address 0x4c25406 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==18866==    at 0x4A07152: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:363)
==18866==    by 0x40461C: main (main.C:90)
```

The problem is with the Employee constructor

```
Employee::Employee(const char* name, int wage, char* hours[]):
employeeName( name), hourlyWage(wage)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++) {
        string s(hours[i]);
        workHours.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

specifically in the line

```
    string s(hours[i]);
```

the array was initialized like so:

```
for (int ii=0;ii<7 && wrongParams == false;ii++)
        {
            z_str = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
            if (z_str)
            {
                strncpy(workHours[ii],z_str,6);
            }
```

I checked and all the strings are null terminated.
Also, can workHours be list-initialized?
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: You really should compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`) -perhaps you already do- and learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and print `i` and `hours[i]` at relevant breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The only allocation for workHours we see is this strncpy.

```
strncpy(workHours[ii],z_str,6);
```

Where did you allocate space for workHours?  Can we see the line from main.c line 90.

It seems that it is one character to short based on this error message.

```
Address 0x4c25406 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==18866==    at 0x4A07152: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:363)
==18866==    by 0x40461C: main (main.C:90)
```

Main.c line 90 is where you may have allocated it.  Also any other place in your code that you are using workHours make sure you are not doing a strcpy of a default value that may append a null past the 6 bytes allocated.

Comment: `strncpy` doesn't add a byte over the size it was given. The problem is that it's not guaranteed to null-terminate.

Comment: good point.  The problem may be that a strcpy was performed on the variable before the strncpy.  We need to see the new from main.c line 90.